# Need help in sharepoint sharepoint list Item ID field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Requesting to check the below code:

```
<Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
<Field Name="ID">4<Field>
<Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field></Method>
<Method ID="2" Cmd="New"><Field Name="ID" >6</Field>
<Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field></Method>
<Method ID="3" Cmd="Update">
<Field Name="ID" >8</Field>
<Field Name="Field_LookUp_Name">ID</Field>
</Method>
<Method ID="4" Cmd="Delete">
<Field Name="ID" >16</Field>
<Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
</Method>
```

The above code I got from MSDN site, in the explanation Field Name="ID" is nothing but list Item ID. Based on what or how they are getting above field Name ID like: 4, 6, 8 16......Please somebody help me I am not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Field Name="ID" is the auto-generated unique item id for each and every item added to the list.

Whenever you enter any new item to list sharepoint automatically assigns unique ID to list item.

Regards.